# Group by based on text in a comma separated column in Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a Data table that has comma separated columns. I want to group by data based on each value in the comma separated column.

```
Date        Investment Type                                    Medium
1/1/2000    Mutual Fund, Stocks, Fixed Deposit, Real Estate    Own, Online,Through Agent
1/2/2000    Mutual Fund, Stocks, Real Estate                   Own
1/3/2000    Fixed Deposit                                      Online
1/3/2000    Mutual Fund, Fixed Deposit, Real Estate            Through Agent
1/2/2000    Stocks                                             Own, Online,                               Through Agent
```

I have to group by Medium and Investment type as given below. The Medium is given as input to the software I am writing.

Medium        Investment Type   Date

```
Online        Stocks            1/2/2000,1/1/2000
Own           Mutual Fund       1/1/2000,1/3/2000
```

I have done search using the input I receive and I do get the results. But I am not able to get into the aggregated format that I want. 
I am new to Python and Pandas. Appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Please share your result

Comment: I am using isin() to search for input in the df and I get the df as result. I need help in aggregating the content if the search based on input is successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First extract values in `Medium` column by list with [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) and regex word boundary:

```
L = ['Online','Own']
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in L)
df['New_Medium'] = df.pop('Medium').str.findall('('+ pat + ')').str.join(', ')
#remove rows with empty values
df = df[df['New_Medium'].astype(bool)]

print (df)
       Date                                  Investment Type   New_Medium
0  1/1/2000  Mutual Fund, Stocks, Fixed Deposit, Real Estate  Own, Online
1  1/2/2000                 Mutual Fund, Stocks, Real Estate          Own
2  1/3/2000                                    Fixed Deposit       Online
4  1/2/2000                                           Stocks  Own, Online
```

Last get all combinations with `product` and last aggregate `join`:

```
from  itertools import product
df1 = pd.DataFrame([j for i in df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(',\s*')).values 
                      for j in product(*i)], columns=df.columns)
df = df1.groupby(['Investment Type','New_Medium'])['Date'].agg(', '.join).reset_index()
print (df)
  Investment Type New_Medium                          Date
0   Fixed Deposit     Online            1/1/2000, 1/3/2000
1   Fixed Deposit        Own                      1/1/2000
2     Mutual Fund     Online                      1/1/2000
3     Mutual Fund        Own            1/1/2000, 1/2/2000
4     Real Estate     Online                      1/1/2000
5     Real Estate        Own            1/1/2000, 1/2/2000
6          Stocks     Online            1/1/2000, 1/2/2000
7          Stocks        Own  1/1/2000, 1/2/2000, 1/2/2000
```

Comment: Ok, How do I take an input and perform the aggregation based on the input?

Comment: @Sid - Can you expalin more? Do you think filtering like [boolean indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas) ?

Comment: @jezrale Assume that the Input from user is "Online,Own" and so the above aggregation has to be done only for "Online" and "Own" options of medium. Hope its clear now.

Comment: @Sid - Yes, I understand. Is not possible first create all combination like my answer and then filtering?

Comment: The Product is creating cartesian product and so it contains combination of each element in each list with the other lists. thats making the tasks of filtering difficult. I am trying to filter the data first, then split if there is a match and aggregate the content. Any help for this is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @Sid - oops, I find bug - need `findall` for return all possible values of `Medium`, edited answer.

Comment: Your solution worked well. But the requirement is changed. Now if there is a match of Medium, I have to do aggregation based on each Investment type, Also, the Medium level grouping should be at list level and not at Individual item from List. i.e of Medium is [Online, Own]. Group data by [Online, Own] for each investment type that is found when we search in df for the Medium list.

Comment: I have posted a new question and its here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52199952/aggregate-based-on-each-item-in-a-special-character-seperated-column-in-pandas

Comment: @Sid - Please give me some time, because meeting.